# Entity Framework 4 One-Way Nav / Relation. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to make a basic `Address` class, that many different other classes can have (a Company can have a billing address and a shipping address, each employee has a home address, etc...).  I am doing this model-first in EF4, and I thought I could do a 1-way-navigation, but this does not work. Here is what I have:

The edmx model. Note that I created a 1-1 relation, then deleted the navigation property on `Address` so that just `Companies` and `Employees` reference an `Address` but the address does not reference its owner.

[image: Entity Framework 4 Model]

The generated SQL looks correct, in that it creates all 3 tables, then enforces the Company -> Address and the Employee -> Address relationships, and does *not* enforce an Address -> Company or Address -> Employee relationship.

```
-- Creating table 'Addresses'
CREATE TABLE [Addresses] (
    [Id] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Street] nvarchar(4000)  NOT NULL,
    [City] nvarchar(4000)  NOT NULL,
    [State] nvarchar(4000)  NOT NULL,
    [Zip] nvarchar(4000)  NOT NULL
);
GO

-- Creating table 'Companies'
CREATE TABLE [Companies] (
    [Id] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] nvarchar(4000)  NOT NULL,
    [Address_Id] int  NOT NULL
);
GO

-- Creating table 'Employees'
CREATE TABLE [Employees] (
    [Id] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] nvarchar(4000)  NOT NULL,
    [Address_Id] int  NOT NULL
);
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [Address_Id] in table 'Companies'
ALTER TABLE [Companies]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_CompanyAddress]
    FOREIGN KEY ([Address_Id])
    REFERENCES [Addresses]
        ([Id])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

-- Creating foreign key on [Address_Id] in table 'Employees'
ALTER TABLE [Employees]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_EmployeeAddress]
    FOREIGN KEY ([Address_Id])
    REFERENCES [Addresses]
        ([Id])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Now I want to insert a `Company` and its `Address`...

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var context = new Model1Container();
        context.AddToCompanies(new Company
        {
            Name = "TestCompany",
            Address = new Address
            {
                Street = "TestAddress"
            }
        });
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

This test fails on `SaveChanges()` with the error:

> System.Data.UpdateException: Entities in 'Model1Container.Addresses' participate in the 'EmployeeAddress' relationship. 0 related 'Employee' were found. 1 'Employee' is expected.

So it looks like EF is trying to enforce the non-navigable Address -> Employee relationship on the Company's Address...

How can I make this work? It seems like this kind of relationship would be fairly common practice... Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make it work. The enforcement is not in the database but in your model. You told EF that `Address` cannot exist without both `Company` and `Employee` (those one-to-one relations) - if fails before any SQL is generated. Moreover if you check the generated SQL those relations are not one-to-one but one-to-many because EF doesn't support this kind of one-to-one relation (it supports it only if dependent entity's PK is FK to principal entity).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What would be the "correct" way to model this in EF? In C# classes, I basically want: `class Address { }` and `class Employee { public Address EmployeeAddress; }` and `class Company { public Address CompanyAddress; }` Is there really no way to model that relationship in EF?

Comment: What is the point of storing addresses in separate table if they cannot be reused? It looks more like you need a complex type. In case of entity you must start with changing relation to 1:0..1

Comment: I think a Complex Type is indeed what I actually want. That properly separates the data in an `Address` type in C#. In the DB, it stores all the fields in the same table, but I guess that doesn't matter. I think I was just applying Object-Oriented logic to the DB layout, which is wrong. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thank you @LadislavMrnka for the answer but I still can't see the solution. Let's say I have Students, Teachers, and Employees, each with a few Addresses. I don't know how many addresses they will have (1 to many addresses for each can be added). What's the best design?